# ORMLite, how to add a one-to-may relationship in the onUpgrade method?

Tags: android, sqlite, ormlite, foreign-collection

I have a deployed app with its own db. In this db there is a table named "notes".
Now I need to add a table "comments", which will contain the comments to the notes.

I need to add a foreign collection in order to have a one-to-many relationship between the "notes" table and the "comments" one (a note may have multiple comments). It is easy to do this when the db is created for the first time, but how can I add the reference from "notes" to "comments" when the db already exists?

I can create the table "comments" with the `TableUtils` class; what statement(s) should I execute in order to link "notes" and "comments"?

Comment: ormlite does not create foreign keys in database schema, so you don't need to do anything more than creating "comments" table with TableUtils.

Comment: Is it sufficient to add a foreign key in the table "comments" pointing to "notes"?

Comment: You should directly run sql statements to create foreign constraints on comments table (alter table ...)